# Android navigation with bottomNavigationView and TabLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview, android-navigation

Im working on an app project where the basic flow goes:
Login/Register Screen -> Bottom Navigation Screen with 4 tabs. One of these tabs will have a tabLayout inside of it. I am trying to do this with a single activity, only using fragments, but I'm not sure how to implement this using navigation graphs. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the navigation Behavior in the following project that mimics your requirements

It should be a good helping hand for you.

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**GITHUB REPO**  **https://github.com/usman14/AndroidNavigationComponent**